# javascript function that is not working but does not display any mistakes

Tags: javascript, function

I've done a function in javascript in roder to calcuate amount of fees for a advocate cabinet.

They ask me to do this, in fact it is proportional to the amount of the file. and it is degressif.

the more is the amount then the percentage will be less, but for each .

In fact When I have no initial payment it calculate fine. when I have a payment registered it does not display anything And I have no error mistakes in the console.

here is the function I've done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function hono(p1,p2,p3,p4,t1,t2,t3,type,versement,montantacompte)
     {
         var p1             = 5000.00;
         var p2             = 5000.01;
         var p3             = 8000.00;
         var p4             = 8000.01;
         var t1             = 17.00;
         var t2             = 10.00;
         var t3             = 6.00;
         var type           = "d";
         var versement      = 150.00;
         var montantacompte = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;


         if (type== "d")
            {
                if(versement== 0.00 && montantacompte <= p1)
                {
                    reste1= montantacompte;
                    pc= t1/100;
                    taux1= pc+1;
                    h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
                    honoraires=h1;
                    document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
                    document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
                }
                else if(versement < p1 && (versement + montantacompte) <= p1)
                {
                    reste1= montantacompte;
                    pc= t1/100;
                    taux1= pc+1;
                    h1= (reste1*taux1)-reste1;
                    honoraires= h1;
                    document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
                    document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
                }
                else if(versement <= p1 && (versement+montantacompte)>= p2 && (versement+montantacompte)<=p3)
                {
                    reste1=p1-versement;
                    pc=t1/100;
                    taux1=pc+1;
                    h1=(reste1*taux1)-reste1;
                    reste2=montantacompte-reste1;
                    pc2=t2/100;
                    taux2=pc2+1;
                    h2=(reste2*taux2)-reste2;
                    honoraires=h1+h2;
                    document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
                    document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('taux-2').value=t2;
                    document.getElementById('palier2').value=Math.round(h2*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
                }
                else if (versement==0.00 && montantacompte>=p2 && montantacompte <=p3)
                {
                    reste2=montantacompte-p1;
                    reste1=p1;
                    pc=(t1/100);
                    taux1=pc+1;
                    h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
                    pc2=(t2/100);
                    taux2=pc2+1;
                    h2=((reste2*taux2)-reste2);
                    honoraires=(h1+h2);
                    document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
                    document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('taux-2').value=t2;
                    document.getElementById('palier2').value=Math.round(h2*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
                }
                else if(versement<=p3 && versement>=p2 && (versement+montantacompte)>=p2 && (versement+montantacompte)<=p3)
                {
                reste1=montantacompte;
                pc=(t2/100);
                taux1=pc+1;
                h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
                honoraires=h1;  
                document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
                document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
                }
                else if(versement>=p2 && versement<=p3 && (versement+montantacompte)>=p4)
                {
                reste1=p4-versement;
                pc=(t2/100);
                taux2=pc+1;
                h2=((reste1*taux2)-reste1);
                reste2=montantacompte-reste1;
                pc2=(t3/100);
                taux3=pc2+1;
                h3=((reste2*taux3)-reste2);
                honoraires=(h2+h3);
                document.getElementById('taux-3').value=t3;
                document.getElementById('palier3').value=Math.round(h3*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('taux-2').value=t2;
                document.getElementById('palier2').value=Math.round(h2*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
            }
            else if(versement==0.00 && montantacompte>=p4)
            {
                reste1=p1;
                reste2=p3-p2;
                pc=(t1/100);
                taux1=pc+1;
                h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
                pc2=(t2/100);
                taux2=pc2+1;
                h2=((reste2*taux2)-reste2);
                reste3=(montantacompte-reste1-reste2);
                pc3=(t3/100);
                taux3=pc3+1;
                h3=((reste3*taux3)-reste3);
                honoraires=(h1+h2+h3);
                document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
                document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('taux-2').value=t2;
                document.getElementById('palier2').value=Math.round(h2*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('taux-3').value=t3;
                document.getElementById('palier3').value=Math.round(h3*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
            }
        else if(versement>=p4)
            {
                reste3=montantacompte;
                pc3=(t3/100);
                taux3=pc3+1;
                h3=((reste3*taux3)-reste3);
                honoraires=(h3);

                document.getElementById('taux-3').value=t3;
                document.getElementById('palier3').value=Math.round(h3*100)/100;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
            }
        }
        if (type=="l")
        {
        pc1=(t1/100);
        taux1=pc1+1;
        honoraires=montantacompte*taux1;
        document.getElementById('taux-1').value=t1;
        document.getElementById('palier1').value=Math.round(h1*100)/100;
        document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=Math.round(honoraires*100)/100;
        }
    </script>
```

Moreover all function use the case `if(versement== 0.00 && montantacompte <= p1)` and after, and so on `else if(versement < p1 && (versement + montantacompte) <= p1)` until the end.

I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: This is a lot of code to try and understand simply by reading it. Is it possible to replicate it using http://jsfiddle.net and give examples of exactly what the problem is (with values)?

Comment: Why are you declaring `p1`, `p2`, etc. as function parameters and then also declaring them with `var` and setting their values?

Comment: are you missing by mistake a closing `}` at the end of the function?

Comment: here is the egzample. http://jsfiddle.net/KUMSG/ in fact all is in the function hon() when you look at the var versement when it is at 0 all works fine . when you write an anmount in the input called montantacompte. It works fine in the table below it calculate the feees. but when the var versement is not equal to zero in the javascript it dfoes not work more. I do not understand why

Comment: I'm not sure comparing float values like this `versement==0.00` is the best idea considering that floats are not super accurate...If you're working with money think about storing wholes and cents in separate objects.

Comment: Oh it seemes to be verry hard for me. So Do you think it is really necessary or it can work using the cay that propose to me Sir Denis Mazourick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to "fix" that by replacing:

```
var montantacompte = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;
```

by

```
var montantacompte = parseFloat(document.getElementById("montantacompte").value);
```

It seems that there's a mess with types - when you get the field value, it is string so any other operations (like (versement+montantacompte) ) will be done with strings, not with numbers.

Comment: Oh thanks because of you it works fine. I don't know why It has stop works, because UI used that code before and it worked fine.

Thank you verry muche for your help, it works fine.

do you think it is better for me to change all var using that code?

Comment: For sure, yes, if they're coming from user inputs. If they're constants and are numeric constants - you don't need to change them.